# Populating a dropdown based on selection in another dropdown in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

hoping someone can point out where I am going wrong. I am working on an MVC 5 ASP.NET application. In my View I have a form which, amongst other controls, has 2 dropdown boxes.The first dropdown is populated with values in the Viewbag, but I want to populate the second dropdown based on the value selected in the first dropdown. I've read lots of other posts but still can't work it out.

Here is the code for the dropdowns.

```
@Html.DropDownList("EquipmentPortList", new SelectList(ViewBag.EquipmentPortList, "hvid", "hvnamn"), "--Select Equipment--")

@Html.DropDownList("PortConnectedList", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "--Select Port--")
```

Here is the change event code for the first dropdown :-

```
$(document).on('change', '#EquipmentPortList', function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetPortInt", "bearers")';
    var ports = $('#PortConnectedList');
    var id = $(this).val();

    $.getJSON(url, { portid: id }, function (response) {
        ports.empty();
        $.each(response, function (index, item) {
            ports.append($('</option>').text(item.portnamn).val(item.portid));
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the method in the controller :-

```
public ActionResult GetPortInt(int portid)
{
    var PortConnectedList = from h in nadb.hvportar
                            where h.porthvid == portid && (h.portnamn.Contains("NT") || (h.portnamn.Contains("Port")) || (h.portnamn.Contains("/")))
                            orderby h.portid
                            select new { h.portid, h.portnamn };

    return Json(PortConnectedList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

OK, so the first dropdown populates correctly, and when I select a value I can see (using alerts) that the change event fires and the value is correctly selected.

I can see with the use of a breakpoint that the method is triggered and returns the correct data from the database, but after that I don't know what is wrong as the dropdown does not populate.

I picked up the code change event code from another post and amended it to fit my own project but I can't see what I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: Add a `console.log(item.portid + ': ' + item.portnamn);` in your `$.each()` code and check what the output is

Comment: I also recommend you look at the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) - your code fails if your editing existing data, or you need to return the view in the POST method (the 2nd dropdownlist will be empty despite the user previously selecting a value)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I've added that in but no idea where I should be seeing the output, not used that before.

Comment: Use your browser tools (F12) and inspect the output in the browser console. You should not be writing scripts until you learn the basics of how to debug them. For Chrome - refer [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Comment: Stephen, your DotnetFiddle link actually showed me the answer. This line :- `ports.append($('</option>').text(item.portnamn).val(item.por‌​tid));` Should read `ports.append($('<option></option>').text(item.portnamn).val(‌​item.portid));` Once I changed that it worked. Can you post an answer so I can accept it ? Many thanks.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer and accept it (I'm about to sign off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephen, your DotnetFiddle link actually showed me the answer. This line :-

```
ports.append($('</option>').text(item.portnamn).val(item.por‌​‌​tid));
```

Should read

```
ports.append($('<option></option>').text(item.portnamn).val(‌​‌​item.portid));
```

Once I changed that it worked. Many thanks.